# Define API url in a redux reactjs application

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, global-variables

Searching around the web but didn't find really an example of explanation for it. Where and how should we define a 'global' api url in a redux application?

As we could have many action holders it would be nice to have just one global var containing the api url we're working with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but I for once declare all my api url's in a file: `export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';` and import this url in my files: `import {API_URL} from "./path.js";`

Comment: You are right! What file name or in what directory you are storing these kind of globals?

Comment: I call the filename `RestAPI.js`. But you can obviously name it whatever you want. I have 4 URL's in this file, one for each microservice and I import the URL I currently need in my components. But I'm not a reactjs guru and there might be a better solution :)

Comment: We will see some upcoming comments but you helped me out with this one already. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a definitive answer, but you can use libraries like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) which wrap an API for your application.

I personally create a config file in my application and have it export a config object which has these application-wide properties.

Comment: This sounds great, I do use axios! Can you provide an example? :)